# Is there a new app logic to ask permissions with new privacy indicator of Android 12 and later?

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions, privacy

I have an app that uses camera and microphone for call feature. On android 11 and older there is no problem. I'm asking the permissions on the manifest xml file.

But, on android 12 and later, since Google added the privacy indicator, my users are turning paranoid, they are afraid I'm spying on them because the green indicator on the top right of the bar is always displayed, even when navigating in the app, when no call is established. Some of them are fearing my app.

Is there a new logic in react native to ask permissions in a right place now ? Is this a normal behavior of Android 12+ ?

What I was expecting is that the green indicator is displayed only when the camera/microphone are really in use, that means during a call.